# editActionsForRowAtIndexPath was called but no action button is shown when the UITableViewCell is slided

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitableviewrowaction

I implemented editActionsForRowAtIndexPath and commitEditingStyle the swipe is working but no action buttons are  shown on the UITableViewCell

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]? {  

    let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Normal, title: "Delete" , handler: { (action:UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath:NSIndexPath!) -> Void in  
          // I did some work here  
    })  

    return [deleteAction]  
}
```

Does anyone have an idea how to get the action buttons to show when sliding? (Currently, the cell slides but behind it is a white background with no action buttons. Also clicking this white background provokes no response of any kind)

Note:  I implemented editActionsForRowAtIndexPath  in another ViewController and it works. (The action buttons both appear and response to click events)

Comment: Did you implement the `canEditRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: yes I did but still not working

Comment: Post your `commitEditingStyle` code plz

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and in my case I realized that my custom cell was way to wide for the table view. I noticed this because the accessory was not shown. Once I ran it on the iPad Emulator, I saw the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

The event should be `commitEditingStyle` here to use swipe button actions

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete) {
            // handle delete (by removing the data from your array and updating the tableview)
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

commitEditingStyle is empty because it is required  for  sliding. editActionsForRowAtIndexPath is implemented and this works in one viewController but does not work for another

The code is as follow

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    }


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]? {

    let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Normal, title: "Delete" , handler: { (action:UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath:NSIndexPath!) -> Void in
        //some code here
    })


    return [deleteAction]
}
```